Is it acceptable to have nail penetrations in a hot-mop shower pan?
We're currently living through the nightmare of having bought a brand new house where the primary shower started leaking.
Builder warranty was used and they ripped out all the tile, mud, and hot mop in the pan and 2 feet up from the pan. The smoking gun was compromised hot mop that was cracked below the dam level, most likely done by the tile lath tradesmen to make the surface flat for the tile.
Tile had to be demolished 2 ft from the shower dam/pan or the hot mop folks wouldn't redo it.
Hot mop was redone and tile lath subcontractor put in the lath and nailed it in all over the hot mop. Some nails are within 1 inch of the dam which seems to be a California code violation. Minimum of 1 inch distance from the dam. Some nails were caulked some nails weren't.
Should there be any nails in the hot mop? The Internet doesn't seem to agree on this and the builder and tradesmen don't seem to agree on it. The hot mop folks said no nails in the tar. The tile lath guys said they can't get the lath to lay flat without nails and that's how it's done.
What was the point of hot mopping 2 feet up just to put nails in it? They caulked all the nails before finishing the "scratch/mud/cement" due to my concern this morning but this whole debacle has me questioning what's a best practice vs what's actual code. I asked the tile lath boss about it being code to have a minimum of 1 inch above the dam for nails and he said "It's coded." This didn't instill confidence that he knows what building codes are. Construction supes didn't let on what they thought and tried to mask their concern but not very well. I get the feeling everyone wants this job to be done including me as the tile guys are coming tomorrow. Am I going to have a home owners insurance claim in my future?




Where is this being built?   I have never used lath in a shower. and have been building them for 40 years.   Cement board is used in most every case and when it is not, Schluter Kerdi board is used.  Lath seem to be a 1950s type of method!

"Hot mop" and lath are still popular for some reason in California.

Not good for obvious reasons.

@RMDman Orange County California is the location and I agree with those points but the shower is really large and as I understand it Kerdi board is only made in "standard" sizes. There is no reason they couldn't have used cement board though.

Kerdi comes in up to 4'x8' sheets.  I have used it and Durock in "Really Big " showers. Both are easily seamed.  Lath is still a 1950s way of doing things. If this were in Somalia or off the grid in Alaska where materials are far away and difficult to move I could understand.  But using an archaic and problematic way to do something when easy, quick, better methods and materials are readily available is foolish.
